# Store Google Form Responses in 3 different spreadsheets depending on form choices

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have created a [form](http://goo.gl/forms/sGn2WBY5FA) in which students have to tell if they've formed a group of 4, 5 or 6 members and correspondingly fill out the email id's of all members in the group.
Right now, all the responses land in a single document, like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bCqv09S3OID_iC126WlINfd18DqUdk2-CzoZ9xb1ujE/edit?usp=sharing)

I want that depending on the group size, 3 different spreadsheets be created. To say, All group of 4 responses in 1 spreadsheet, all group of 5 in one spreadsheet and all group of 6 responses in one spreadsheet. So 3 spreadsheets for the 3 group options. 
I was going through the web and I see its possible via App scripts but I couldnt figure out how. Any leads on this?

Answer (score 1):

no need to use script for this which is not trivial to do and handle all possible errors.

instead simply use a combination of importRange and filter/query to the other spreadsheets from the master responses.

by using spreadsheet formulas your spreadsheets will always update correctly and instantly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) on the form which is called on form submission. Rather than using the default functionality of adding all responses to a "Form Responses" sheet, your script would then take the raw form data and add it to the appropriate sheet based on the group size.

Comment: You would take your [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) from the trigger and use your script to process it and add it to each sheet.

Comment: Alright, I'll see how it goes. Thank you for taking time to answer :)